# What happens if you orbit the solar system via FTL drive then come back?

Tags: science-based

I've always heard that FTL travel would be essentially going back in time, but it's conventionally used in terms of traveling interstellar distances.  So, if you orbited the solar system via FTL travel (I chose the solar system just for the lower centripetal force vs. orbiting the earth at above light speed, I assume it would be too tight a curve), assuming this has been achieved, and we're talking say, Star Wars style hyper-drive rather than a warp/Alcubierre drive and somehow you just push on through light speed with propulsion, when you slowed down would you be in earth's past time frame?

Or would you just have wasted a bunch of time and energy?  And of course now I'm realizing that this is basically the superman spins round the earth and it reverses thing from the movie (spoilers, that's what was supposedly happening there, backwards time travel).  Sorry for the vague-ass initial question, and feel free to recommend I throw this at the physics boards.

Comment: Hello Jimmy. Welcome to the site! This question doesn't appear to be the correct format for this site. As it is, this question (or something like it) should be posted on the [Physics SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: So, is this a 'how does FTL travel = time travel' question, or a 'how far would you have to go to orbit the solar system' question? And what do you mean by 'solution'? FTL travel is impossible, as is time travel, so you'd have to solve a lot of things before doing this.

Comment: Hi Jimmy, try to add some more text to your question to make it more clear what you are asking. If you are in doubt try and look in to some other questions, preferred the ones with many points as inspiration.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh It is impossible with our current tech. A speculative [Alcubierre drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive) could still be used, although I doubt that is what OP is asking for....

Comment: Is this on topic or simple not clear? With [a lot of] rephrasing this would fit within the scopes of this site or our [Physics Stack exchange](http://physics.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @DJMethaneMan Looks to me to not be about worldbuilding, and as such, off topic for us. If the question is rewritten, it could potentially be on topic either here or on Physics, depending on the focus of the question, but either way it's a major rewrite (and as such not something that should be done by someone not the OP). As the question is *now*, I agree that it is unclear. The first thought that hit me when I saw the question title was "what do you mean orbit the solar system via FTL drive?", and the question did *nothing* to clear up that initial confusion.

Comment: Thanks for joining the site!  Unfortunately, there's a lot of questions that we cannot answer very well on Stack Exchange.  In your question's case, the biggest challenge I see is that you have not chosen a FTL drive technology to poke at with your question.  Science fiction literally has dozens if not hundreds of flavors of FTL, each with its own particular effects on time.  For example, turning yourself into tachyons and orbiting a planet is often treated as something which results in backwards time travel.  However, a wormhole would just be point to point, making for a hard answer.

Comment: Alcubierre drives, as many have mentioned, are theoretically valid within the ream of Einstein's relatavistic model of the world, but they would not allow for backwards time travel.  So you see, there are many approaches.  Unfortunately, StackExchange's question/answer format does not allow for the kinds of conversation-formatted discussion required to pin this question down into something we can answer.  Alternatively, you could ask for a [reference-request] of existing science fiction FTL approaches which allow backwards time travel.  While bordering on a "list question," it should be valid.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments guys, just a total n00b here who was maybe too tipsy when I found this board.  I hope the changes offer some clarity.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no way to travel back in time. You could in theory leave in 2050 and come back in 2200 if you accelerated to near the speed of light. I am not exactly sure how you would get back to your own time, though. If you simply want FTL, then your best bet would be an [Alcubierre drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive).

Comment: I recommend reading [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52249/how-does-faster-than-light-travel-violate-causality) if you are interested in the topic of time travel.

Comment: You should understand *why* FTL implies time travel. Learn about S-T diagrams and plotting "events" in space and time, and world lines of normal relativistic travel. Then plot some suplerlumal transits and you will see that the meaning of *velocity* (FTL) doesn't even have a clear single interpretation.  The bit about orbits and such is irrelevant.  Do donuts if you want. Go from here to a point near Jupiter 5 minutes later.  The key is realizing that it doesn't matter what reference frame you're in.

Comment: "somehow you just push on through light speed with propulsion" er, no.  Imagine a tomato in a vice, gets closer to, zero width as you crank it harder. Can you just push through zero and turn it inside out?  You need to hit Physics.SE and look up some general intro on Special Relativity.